# Heading Numbers on the Rise Side

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, numbering, field-codes

I desire to create a heading style so that each heading is automatically enumerated and multileveled, but the numerbs appear on the right side of the line whereas the words appear on the left.

Example:

```
First Heading                         1
   First Subheading                 1.1
   Second Subheading                1.2
Second Heading                        2
   Next Subheading                  2.2
```

*(Note: I only included the headings in the example above, but there would be body text between each heading.)*

Is this possible with automated enumeration in Word that I can save as a style? Is it possible with field codes? I would prefer not to use VBA is possible.

Comment: I am thinking Right-to-left settings. Just a thought. If you use these in a traditional Table of Contents it is going to get confusing! You could get something that looks like this using a Table but your headings would be separate from the numbers and it would be a pain to edit.